# Why does one of my IF statements not work in Python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, printing, logic

This is my code, it works perfectly except for the last if statement.

I want to when the list members become 0 the bot send this message:

```
"No One"
```

This code works perfectly when the list reaches 2 bot say: fix.

But when it reaches 0, it doesn't say anything!

```
 from telegram.ext import Updater , CommandHandler , Filters , 
 CommandHandler , MessageHandler
 from telegram import MessageEntity
 from telegram import ParseMode , InputTextMessageContent

 updater = Updater("989165404:AAF8DEjyunwrb88-1G8w62cGItzXj1J618g")

list = []
wordsm=["m"]
wordsn=["n"]

def msg_filter(bot , update):

    if any (i in update.message.text for i in wordsm):
        list.append("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = 
        "\n".join(list))

       if len(list)==2:
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "FiX!")


         if any (j in update.message.text for j in wordsn):
         list.remove("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
          bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = 
         "\n".join(list))


         if len(list)==0:
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "No 
        One")

       print(list)
       print(len(list))

       updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text 
       ,msg_filter ))
       updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: You should indent your code properly, python code blocks are all about indentation.

Comment: `if len(list)==0` is inside `if len(list)==2` block, therefore will never fire (if list is of size 2, then it can't be of size 0).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the indentation. I think you have put the "if len(list)==0:" inside "if len(list)==2:"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not looking at this right, but it looks like your

```
if len(list)==0:
```

is nested inside your

```
if len(list)==2:
```

Both conditions will never both be true simultaneously, so it never enters that condition.

Maybe it should instead be:

```
if len(list)==0:
    enter code here
elif len(list)==2:
    enter your code here
```